# In clause with 2 fields on 1 table

Tags: sql-server, in-clause

I have a query :

```
 SELECT 
   MAX(date), 
   logId,
   computerId
 FROM 
   logTable
 WHERE logId IN ('1','2','3')
```

But I want the IN clause test the computerId too like this :

logId = '1' **and** computerId = '998874',

logId = '2' **and** computerId = '334211',
...

How to do this ?

Comment: Are there specific pairs, like your example? OS if logid = '1' then computerid must equal '998874' and only '998874'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to replace the `IN`statement with multiple `OR`statements

```
 SELECT  MAX(date)
        ,  logId
        , computerId
 FROM   logTable
 WHERE  (logId = '1' AND computerid = '998874')
        OR (logId = '2' AND computerid = '334211')
```

Alternatively, if you have many conditions, it might be more readable to create an in-memory table for them and join on these conditions

```
;WITH Conditions (logID, computerid) AS (
  SELECT '1', '998874'
  UNION ALL SELECT '2', '334211'
)
SELECT  MAX(date)
        ,  logId
        , computerId
FROM   logTable lt
       INNER JOIN Conditions c ON c.logID = lt.LogID 
                                  AND c.computerid = lt.computerID
```

Comment: Doubtfull but to be sure, you'd have to compare both options. Note that the performance difference for this particular case would not be noticable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with an `IN` clause.  I think you need a conditional where.  So:

```
SELECT MAX(date), logId, computerId
FROM logTable
WHERE (logId = 1 AND computerId = '998874') OR
      (logId = 2 AND computerId = '334211') OR
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` in SQL Server does not support tuples. You can use `EXISTS` and a table expression. 2008 syntax below.

```
SELECT MAX(l.date),
       l.logId,
       l.computerId
FROM   logTable l
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   (VALUES ( '1', '998874'),
                              ('2', '334211')) v(logId, computerId)
              WHERE  v.computerId = l.computerId
                     AND v.logId = l.logId)  
GROUP  BY l.logId,
          l.computerId
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
   MAX(date), 
   logId,
   computerId
 FROM 
   logTable
 WHERE (logId = '1' AND computerId = '998874')
    OR (logId = '2' AND computerId = '334211')
    OR (logId = '3' AND computerId = '123456')
 GROUP BY logId, computerId
```